# Expiry Date of Signature

Tags: ethereum, signature, web3js, public-key

I am signing an arbitrary string by

```
const ts = Date.now();
const hash = await web3.utils.sha3(anystring+ts);
const sign = await web3.eth.personal.sign(hash, account);
```

and check the address by

```
const address = await web3.eth.accounts.recover(hash, sign);
```

The problem is, that this signature is valid forever.

How is it possible to introduce and expiry date/time?

Answer (score 1):

The signature expiration must be checked at the application level.

The message itself must contain a payload for how long the message is valid.

Then the application checks the timestamp after checking the signature.

Comment: Thank you Mikko. I am using the signature for user authentication for an API. With the recover() I get the user address as proof. However, a "Man in the middle"/"Hacker" could use the msg/signature to pretend to be the user. So, I am looking for a proper way to either invalidate the msg/signature after a usage or add an expiry date/time. I may need to use something like nonce, right?

Comment: `However, a "Man in the middle"/"Hacker" could use the msg/signature to pretend to be the use` No. Make sure you get the signature directly from MetaMask / WalletConnect. There is no man-in-the-middle. This is blockchain.

Comment: But if you are worried just have some timestamp in the message the user is signing and check the signature against that message.

Comment: The user sends the hash with its signature in the https header. The backend calls recover(hash, signature) to check the user's identity. I mean if someone possesses any hash/signature pair he/she can call the API on behalf of the user.

Comment: Ok, undestood. Then in your use case probably a nonce for a message generation on the server-side and then maintaining a counter per user for used nonces could work as well.

Comment: For a POST request, I can just sign the request body of the POST request, since the body's content changes from request to request. However, the GET request is always the same and the signature/hash could be used repeatedly.

Comment: For a POST request, I can just sign the request body of the POST request, since the body's content changes from request to request. However, the GET request is always the same and the signature/hash could be used repeatedly.

Comment: No, you need to have the nonce in the message the user signs in their wallet. It is unrelated to any GET/POST. If you want to ensure that the same message is not subject to reuse end-to-end.

Comment: So how would I do it exactly. Let's say I call https://api.mydomain/userinfo/userxyz and I add the signature and the hash to the header. I want to use the signature and hash to call recover(hash, signature) which returns an address which I check at the API backend site. Once a their person gets any hash/signature pair, he/she can get the user information.

Comment: You sign the message only once for authentication (login) and then generate a session token for the user based on that. Like SSH, etc. work